# How do I create a portable Mac OS flash drive?

Tags: macos, mac, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, portable

How do I create a portable Mac OS flash drive? I installed Linux on my MacBook Air, but I would like to be able to boot into Mac OS to play Minecraft, since it's much faster for some reason. I have a backup of my operating system before I installed Linux, but it's much too big to fit on a flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Mac running macOS, format the drive as GPT (GUID Partition Table) and APFS. Then use the [Mac] App Store app to download the latest macOS installer. Run the installer, and when it asks where you want to install macOS, select the drive you prepared.

There's no good way to accomplish this from Linux. Use a friend's Mac or visit an Apple store or somewhere else you can make use of a Mac already running macOS.

Note that most USB Flash drive sticks have very poor performance for lots of small I/O operations per second (IOPS), even if they have very high sustained read/write speeds. Modern OSes need high IOPS from their boot/root filesystem volume, so be sure to choose a drive that has high IOPS scores. Buying a bare 2.5" SATA SSD and a USB3 to SATA adapter cable is often a better approach for creating an external boot drive, rather than hoping a typical pocketable USB Flash  "stick/keychain/thumb" drive will have the IOPS you need.

Comment: I do have access to another Mac, but is there a way to make a "Live" operating system, like Linux installers? That would eliminate the problem of low IOPS, and would probably extend the drive's lifetime.

Comment: When I try to download "Mac OS Catalina", it says it cannot be installed on this computer.